# Sudden problems with GeoPandas point.x and point.y

Tags: python, geopandas

After a computer switch Geopandas has started to cause me problem. Suddenly I can't extract x and y from a point.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

(gdp=geopandas)

[image: Problem]

Comment: You are using very old version of geopandas. The recent is 0.10.2. Try updating first. Then make sure `df1` is a GeoDataFrame not DataFrame.

Comment: I ran pip install geopandas but the version didn't change. Wonder why I don't get the latest by default?

Comment: did you pass the `--upgrade` flag? i.e., `pip install --upgrade geopandas`

Comment: @tdy That solved it and saved my life! Thx!